# "Meu coração acelera e eu sozinha aqui" — shouldn't it be "[...] e eu estou sozinha aqui"?

Tags: verbos, português-brasileiro, letras-de-músicas

Why is "**Meu coração acelera e eu sozinha aqui**" correct? For the "eu sozinha aqui", shouldn't it be "estou sozinha aqui" because the speaker should be using the verb "estar"?

It's from this part of "A Noite" by Tiê: https://youtu.be/5EE-31DmLZ0?t=45s

Comment: CodeMonkey, See if you like this title. I think it is more explicit than the original one. You can roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: This type of construction is current usage in Brazilian Portuguese. Verb "estar" is implicit in your example.  "Chego em casa, e (encontro) ela de mau humor", "Quando cheguei eles já tinham almoçado, e eu (estava) ali cheio de fome.", "Não me avisaram que havia sido cancelado, e eu ali (esperando) como um palhaço.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s a very standard phrase in both Brazilian and European Portuguese. But your interpretation is correct in that the verb *estar* is implicit there. The structure of this construction is as follows:

> *Statement 1, e eu/tu/ele/etc.* [omitted verb] *Y*

***Y*** says how you are (*aqui sozinha*, *(aqui) à tua espera*) or what you are doing, using the gerund or, in European Portuguese, ***a*** + infinitive (*trabalhando, dormindo, a descansar*), and sets some sort of contrast with *satement 1*. ***Y*** often includes *aqui, ali, lá*, etc. Sometimes these are necessary to indicate location; sometimes they’re optional or just a filler. Examples:

> *Ela foi para a praia, e eu* [omitted *estou*] *aqui trabalhando*.
>
> *Eu estou trabalhando, e ela* [omitted *está*] *na praia de papo para o ar*.

Sometimes we can omit the verb in the first statement too:

> *Eu (aqui) trabalhando, e ela na praia de papo para o ar*

You see which verb is omitted from context. It is usually *estar*, but could be *andar*:

> *Eu estou aqui a trabalhar, e ela* [omitted *anda*] *por aí na vadiagem*.

Here are some quotes from a few household names in Portuguese and Brazilian literature:

> O tempo a correr ***e eu aqui*** de conversa. (Josué Montello, *A Noite sobre Alcântara*, 1978.)
>
> Era o que mais lhe doía. O pai fizera sela para o Imperador montar. ***E ele ali***, naquela beira de estrada, fazendo rédea para um sujeito desconhecido. (José Lins do Rego, *Fogo Morto*, 1943)
>
> Todos os hóspedes fora ou recolhidos aos seus aposentos — ***e ela ali***, toda esbelta no *peignoir* emprestado de uma irmã, dispondo ramos de flores nos vasos (Emília Moncorvo Bandeira de Melo, *A Luta*, 1911.)
>
> Ritinha apareceu: — Ah! Mamede... que horas! ***E eu aqui*** sem almoçar. (Coelho Neto, *Turbilhão*, 1906.)
>
> Duas horas e um quarto! exclamou Taveira, que olhara o relógio. ***E eu aqui***, empregado publico, tendo deveres para com o Estado, logo ás dez horas da manhã. (Eça de Queiroz, *Os Maias*, 1888.)
>
> Se tivesse a tua vida, viveria como Noé. Mas tu estás de palanque e à fresca, ***e eu aqui*** estatelado a dar-te trela. (Júlio Diniz, *As Pupilas do Senhor Reitor*, 1867.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! What's the formal rule for implicit interpretation of a subsequent verb in a sentence and in what circumstances can you implicitly interpret something?

Comment: This particular construction is *X, e eu/tu/ele/etc. [omitted verb] Y*, where *Y* says how you are (sozinho, cheio de fome, todo preocuado, etc.) or what you are doing (using the gerund or, in European Portuguese, ***a*** + infinitive: trabalhando/a trabalhar) and sets some sort of contrast with *X*. For instance: *ela foi para a praia, e eu* [omitted *estou*] *aqui trabalhando* or *eu estou trabalhando, e ela* [omitted *está*] *na praia de papo para o ar*. The omitted verb is typically *estar*, but could be *andar*: *Eu estou aqui a trabalhar, e ela* [omitted *anda*] *por aí na vadiagem*.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Let me know whether the comment above helps.

Comment: Your explanation helped a lot! Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: `Todos os hóspedes fora ou recolhidos aos seus aposentos` - «fora ou»? Infelizmente, a única fonte desse texto que encontro tem o mesmo erro.

Comment: @ANeves Erro?! «Todos os hóspedes [estão] fora [a passear na cidade, por exemplo] ou recolhidos aos seus aposentos.» Este é um caso de dois verbos omissos.

Comment: Ei, que complexidade... percebo, obrigado.